# How do I add an article that is already in Google Scholar to my profile?

Tags: google-scholar

I have authored some publications that are already present in Google Scholar and have citations listed for them, but I see no way to add them to my profile. I see how to add an article with all of the same information manually, but this creates what appears to be an independent (duplicate?) entry for the article, with no citations or links associated. I also see how to get a list of suggested additions, but the articles I'm looking for are not among them.

How do I add an article that is already in Google Scholar to my profile?

Comment: Have you changed your name or institutional affiliation?

Comment: @BrianBorchers: No, but some of the missing papers have (correctly) a slightly different name for me (e.g. initials vs. full first name).

Comment: Has someone else with the same initial/name already claimed the article?

Answer (score 27):

1. `Sign In` to [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/).
2. Click on `My Profile`.
3. Click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button above the article list
4. Click on `Add articles` in the context menu

Comment: Tried that. It doesn't work: "I see how to add an article with all of the same information manually", and the articles are (obviously) not among the list of articles that appear automatically.

Comment: You can add them manually. Google Scholar will probably eventually notice that the two areticles are the same, and suggest combining them. If it's a new article, you can also just wait. I have found that articles usually appear in Google Scholar a few days earlier than they are suggested as additions to my profile.

Comment: May not be what the OP wanted, but this answers my question and the question in the title. Thanks.

Comment: follow the instructions above, then, when offered a search box, enter the title of your article. Then you click on the checkbox next to the identified article and click on the validation button (top-right corner).

Answer (score 1):

1. Sign in to Google Scholar.
2. Find the article in Google Scholar that you would like to add to your profile.
3. Select the *star* (Save) under the article.
4. Click on my library (Top right)
5. Select the article and click the Edit icon (pencil icon on top)
6. You will see the details of the article, copy it as is in Add articles manually. (instructions mentioned above!)

Answer (score 1):

In direct answer to the OP's question...

Do what was mentioned earlier about getting to the Details of the article.

Then copy the *entire* author row (not just your name).

Go back to the Add Articles "+" button above your article list.

In the search bar where your name is, paste that author row you searched for. You should be able to find it now.

Comment: This worked for me immediately. Great answer!

Comment: The answer is not self-contained (__Do what was mentioned earlier__)