# How long does it usually take for published articles to show up on Google Scholar?

Tags: google-scholar

The title pretty much says it all - what's the typical delay with which Google Scholar indexes newly published articles? (Note I'm not talking about citations, but about the article showing up at all.)

Edit: the article in question went for over six months after being published (in a well-regarded Springer journal with its own Wikipedia page) without appearing on Google Scholar, until it received a citation, at which point it was added to Google Scholar almost immediately. One more motivation to write papers that get cited. :)

Edit 2: Another article in an even more mainstream journal took a little over seven weeks.

Comment: Usually a week for me, but it seems to strongly depend on the journal.

Comment: zero, you can add it yourself

Comment: @FábioDias How?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/76627/50533

Comment: @TheFireGuy I don't see what that has to do my question. That answer explains how to add an article already on Google Scholar that one has written to one's personal page, not how to add an article that someone else has written to Google Scholar.

Comment: follow the steps, there is an option to manually add articles.

Comment: @tparker indeed, I read a "my" that wasn't there, my bad :)

Comment: @TheFireGuy Please read my previous comment.

Comment: Google Scholar indexing takes Upto 6 months.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My article showed up in a few days. Since google is crawling, I believe (although I am not certain), that updating other sources such as policy, government, medical repositories and other resource hubs that allow you to update fields, add links etc, without needing to upload the article, increases the external links with the article page. This might not be necessary to expedite the process, but if the article is not showing up within the normal period of time (which could be a week), I believe this would be a good step to take. This advice also applies for anything else such as websites and blogs. Actually my repository link showed up in google before the actual journal page did!

Answer (score 6):

My article was published online in Elsevier journal and it took less than 7 working day to appear in Google Scholar. "Appear" here indicates that I can search the title of my paper in Google Scholar and the website points out my paper seamlessly.

FYI, I received the notification of the paper in my Google Scholar profile in around the same time.

I think, there might be discrepancy between publisher regarding time to appear in Google Scholar.

Answer (score 4):

I have had very varying times.

My most recent one was already there by the time I noticed my online version was up. However, my first one had many issues with Google Scholar, when it was first online they once combined the citations of my paper with someone elses. They then disconnected it and I could not find it again for a few more months. I think it took about 4-6 months overall for this one to appear and work.

Comment: that makes me really sad as my first paper was published on 19th of October, almost 2 weeks passed, and it can't be found in google scholar. Although it is indexed properly in research gate

Answer (score 2):

I have an article that's been on ResearchGate- which google scholar found right away- but it lists + links DOI to the "online first" version of the journal (which is published by Wiley) and this official version still has not shown up in google scholar 7 months later.  (it is also not present in Web of Knowledge - so maybe this is systematic).  Further, my *missing* article cites another one of my articles that *is* in google scholar, and that citation does not appear in google scholar.  So I'm still waiting on this and will update this answer when / if the official version finally shows up.

Comment: Did it eventually sort itself out?

Comment: it did! sorry I didn't circle back. I guess it took less than 4 years