# Why I could not search this paper in Google Scholar?

Tags: google-scholar

I am interested in this paper [An Evaluation of the Potential of NMR Spectroscopy and Computational Modelling Methods to Inform Biopharmaceutical Formulations](http://www.mdpi.com/1999-4923/10/4/165/htm). But it seems that it could not be found on Google Scholar. Can I ask why?

Comment: Perhaps it has not been uploaded to google scholar?

Comment: I think uploading is automatic?

Comment: I don't get it. You're interested in a paper for which you have the direct link. Why do you need Google Scholar?

Comment: Because I mainly use google scholar to search. I just occationally found it somewhere else. So, could you please remove the down-vote?

Comment: Ok so you're question is a duplicate of this?: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/93764/10643

Comment: It is VERY dangerous to make accusations about who gave a downvote (or upvote for that matter), is it easily possible that your question can be downvoted by someone who will not leave a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That paper was published on Friday 21 September 2018. You're asking this question on Sunday 23 September 2018... In my experience it usually takes a week or longer for Google Scholar to index a paper, depending on the journal. Also see [How long does it usually take for published articles to show up on Google Scholar?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/93764/17254) for more information on the variability. The bottom line is that papers don't show up on Google Scholar the instant they are published, so be patient or use other ways of accessing it.