# A recently published article of mine in a reputable Elsevier journal does not show on Google Scholar. Why?

Tags: publications, google-scholar, indexing

I recently published an article in a reputable Elsevier journal, and it is not indexed by Google scholar. Other articles in the same volume of the same journal are indexed on Google Scholar already, so it doesn't seem like it has to do with Google's crawling cycle. I added the article manually to my Google scholar profile, but you can't add a DOI or link to the article so it still just looks like only the Arxiv preprint exists and not the journal publication. What can be done about this?

Comment: Or https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/93764/63475

Comment: Potentially but I've tried the steps suggested there and they have not changed the situation yet

Comment: "it doesn't seem like it has to do with Google's crawling cycle" - that's a bold assumption. If you really strongly suspect there's been an error, write to their support (obviously). Otherwise, don't assume the implementation works in some way which makes sense to *you* - for all we know, it might be "add random 70% from a given volume, then add another 60% from another volume while adding some priority to the first one for future passes". Orchestration/task scheduling is a hard problem in IT, and you may well end up spending hours trying to understand *why* it works the way it does.

Comment: Many journals have the 'next' issue available on line, adding papers as they go. So, other papers may have had a month (or more) to be indexed, while your article was just added and hasn't been seen yet.