# Is it a problem if I add my journal paper manually in Google Scholar?

Tags: publications, google-scholar

Today, my paper was published and it got a DOI number. However, it does not appear in Google Scholar.
After searching the web for the answer, I found that it takes a long time for the paper to show up in Google Scholar. For this reason, I want to ask you: if I add the paper manually to Google Scholar, will that be a problem in the future?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long does it usually take for published articles to show up on Google Scholar?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/93764/how-long-does-it-usually-take-for-published-articles-to-show-up-on-google-schola)

Comment: It does not take that long for a paper to appear on Google scholar.

Comment: Can you manually add papers?