# Can I add a preprint directly to OSF even though it is already published on OSF?

Tags: google-scholar, preprint

So basically, I have this paper my team and I wrote for a data challenge. It's published, and available as a project on [Open Science Framework (OSF)](https://osf.io/). However, it doesn't show up on Google Scholar, and after doing some research, I saw that preprints submitted to OSF directly will get indexed by Google Scholar. Note: I cannot add the paper manually to Google Scholar as I have no prior published papers.

Is it acceptable to submit the paper as a preprint to OSF, even though it's already on OSF as a part of an overarching project (with a DOI and everything)? Let me know if any extra information is needed.

Comment: When was the paper published? It can take some time to show up on Google scholar (say 2-4 weeks sometimes)

Comment: Earlier this month

Comment: @VivaanSinghvi I see! In that case I definitely recommend just waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never uploaded anything to OSF myself, but since the ["Upload a preprint"](https://help.osf.io/article/177-upload-a-preprint) instructions mentions a way to upload the preprint PDF file from an existing project, I would assume the OSF finds the practice acceptable, at least under some conditions (which they don't seem to spell out). I would *guess* it's acceptable for a preprint that's a component of an overarching project, but it's probably worth double-checking with someone more familiar with OSF, or their support.

Even after reading the FAQ I am unclear on whether Google Scholar tends to index projects or not. If I were in your shoes, I would take @leonos' advice of waiting a few weeks to give them a chance to do it. If I have found the right repository, it was apparently only made public five days ago, and Google Scholar often [takes longer than that to index preprints and articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/93764/17254).