# What should I do if Google Scholar doesn't link to the published version even after 7 months?

Tags: publications, google-scholar, preprint

My last paper was published around July 2023 but when I check it on Google Scholar, till now it only shows the preprint version. Because of that, even the latest citations go to my preprint version. I even manually updated my scholar data, but still searching for it only links to the preprint on arXiV.

Although, those in my field of High Energy Physics, use [Inspire](https://inspirehep.net/) to get citation data which mentions both the published and the preprint version. Still, someone who is unaware of Inspire and relies on Google Scholar only gets the Bibtex data for the preprint, which is a big issue for me. How do I resolve it?

Comment: Why is it a big issue?

Comment: Because my colleagues from different fields are unable to find the published version from Google Scholar.

Comment: That's not the problem your title question asks about. Anyways, people should cite the version of your paper that they read. If they read the preprint that's what they should cite.

Comment: Ah true! Maybe I need to rephrase my question.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a satisfactory answer, see also this meta question: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5376/should-we-make-google-scholar-questions-off-topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do nothing.  Google says it can take more than a year for a paper to show up. https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/help.html#coverage

Comment: Basically this. The time to indexing of the published version is [very variable](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/93764/17254). That said, I'd also encourage filling out the journal reference field on arXiv so readers pointed there by Google Scholar or other papers are informed that it's been published.